# How to solve coupled differential equations with additional constant vectors?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I know how to solve coupled differential equations in the form:
$$\frac{d\vec{x}}{dt}=A\vec{x}$$ Where $A$ is a constant matrix. But how would I go about solving a differntial equation like:
$$\frac{d\vec{x}}{dt}=A\vec{x}+\vec{a}$$ Where $\vec{a}$ is a constant vector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The general solution of $\dot{x} = Ax+u$ subject to $x(0)=x_0$ is
$x(t) = e^{At} x_0 + \int_0^t e^{A(t-\tau)} u(\tau)d \tau$. In the above $u(t) = a$.

If $A$ is invertible, this can be simplified to
$x(t) = e^{At} x_0 + A^{-1}(e^{At}-I) a$.

Comment: ...moreover this is called duhamel’s principle and it can be obtained by using an integrating factor (for instance).

Comment: another name is the method of variation of parmeters

Comment: There are many approaches. One could use the Picard iteration to obtain a power series expansion.

Answer (score 1):

Another trick is to reformulate your problem from the affine form into a linear form.
You can do that by expanding your linear system of n dimensions by one dimension.

$$ A' =\left[
\begin{array}{c|c}
A & \vec{a}\\
\hline
  \vec{0}^\intercal & 0
\end{array}
\right]$$

The new initial value is set $x_{n+1}(t_0) = 1$. By doing that we introduce a constant 1 (because $\frac{dx_{n+1}}{dt} = 0$) which gets multiplied by the vector.

The resulting system $\frac{d\vec{x}}{dt} = A' \vec{x}$ you already know how to solve. This transformation is useful if you are dealing with numerical integration code which only takes the linear form.